# SQL Server : order by - column equal to zero or larger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to order a result list by a computed float column A and then a column B.

I would like to first get all rows where the computed field A is larger than zero, then ordered by B. After that all the rows which are zero then ordered by B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
order by case when colA > 0 then 1
              when colA = 0 then 2
              when colA < 0 then 3
         end,
         colB
```